# Convert XML hibernateConfiguration to Java Config?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-java-config

I'm looking to convert this XML to Java Config for Spring:

```
<bean id="hibernateConfiguration" factory-bean="&amp;sessionFactory"
    factory-method="getConfiguration" />
```

And I'm thinking...

```
@Bean
public org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration() {

    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration config = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration();

    //uhhh...

    return config;
}
```

How would I specify the `factory-bean` and `factory-method` params?  Tried looking around on SO, but no luck.

Aside:  the `&amp;` tells Spring to fetch the actual bean

**UPDATE:**

Here is how I am using the bean.  It's a listener that prints out the schema.

```
@Component
public class SchemaExportListener extends AbstractEnvironment implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

       log.debug("onApplicationEvent");

       if (isPrintSchemaEnabled()) {
          log.info("printing schema");

          SchemaExport schema = new SchemaExport(hibernateConfiguration);
          schema.setDelimiter(BaseConstants.SEMI_COLON);

          if(isCreateOutputFile()) {
             schema.setOutputFile(getSchemaOutputPath());
          }
          schema.create(true, false);
       }
    }

    public static boolean isPrintSchemaEnabled() {
       return Boolean.valueOf(getResourceBundle().getString(PRINT_SCHEMA_ENABLED));
    }

    public static boolean isCreateOutputFile() {
       return Boolean.valueOf(getResourceBundle().getString(OUTPUT_FILE_ENABLED));
    }

    public static String getSchemaOutputPath() {
       return getResourceBundle().getString(SCHEMA_OUTPUT_PATH);
    }

    @Autowired
    private Configuration hibernateConfiguration;

    public static final String PRINT_SCHEMA_ENABLED = "enablePrintSchema";
    public static final String SCHEMA_OUTPUT_PATH = "schemaOutputPath";
    public static final String OUTPUT_FILE_ENABLED = "enableSchemaOutputFile";

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchemaExportListener.class);

}
```

As for more XML, it's not all relevant, but since it was requested:

```
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!--Annotated classes redacted -->
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>       
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>         
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariConnectionPool" />
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="${dataSource.dataSourceClassName}" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="30000" />

    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
      <props>
            <prop key="url">${dataSource.url}</prop>
            <prop key="user">${dataSource.username}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${dataSource.password}</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you could add more xml configuration so that it helps us to provide an equivalent java configuration.

Comment: Why aren't you simply using the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` or `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`?

Comment: @sarfaraz Added further detail to question

Comment: @M.Deinium - I'm using the LocalSessionFactoryBean as noted in the additional XML that I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think that you'll need to mention the factory bean or methods in the java config.In your class wire the sessionFactory in class and see if it works

```
@Component
public class SchemaExportListener extends AbstractEnvironment implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

@Autowired
private LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

       log.debug("onApplicationEvent");

       if (isPrintSchemaEnabled()) {
          log.info("printing schema");

          SchemaExport schema = new SchemaExport(localSessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration());
          schema.setDelimiter(BaseConstants.SEMI_COLON);
```

In Java configuration class

```
@Autowired
private LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean;

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
  //return the data source here
}

@Bean(name = "hibernateConfig")
public org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfig() {
    return localSessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration();
}
```

If the autowire of session object fails then try to create on Object in the config like below

```
@Autowired
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(this.getDataSource());
  //sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(this.hibernateProperties());

    return localSessionFactoryBean;
 }
```

For the rest of the configuration refer to some guide or example 
Here are few [example1](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring) [example2](http://www.sivalabs.in/2011/02/springhibernate-application-with-zero.html)

Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: It's still considered a work-around to the actual question, but I am accepting this as the solution (the last section worked for me, rather than providing the getConfig() method).

Answer (score 0):

You can just autowire the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and get the configuration

```
@Autowired
private LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean;

@Bean(name = "hibernateConfig")
public org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfig() {
    return localSessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration();
}
```

Comment: Saw an exception with this work-around: `Factory method 'getHibernateConfig' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration not initialized yet`

Comment: (I renamed the method to `getHibernateConfig()`)